# Rails ActiveRecord how set NULL as Time.now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some table:

```
online | offline
 10:32 | 11:06
 12:28 | 13:04
 14:07 | NULL
```

As you can see, - user is not offline at the time (assume that now is 14:15). And I need to get a duration of all user onlines. If user is not currently offline - I need to get difference Time.now - online.

In my ruby-code I create function:

```
def offline_datetime
  if offline.nil? then Time.current else offline end
end
```

It's ok, but if I have many records it will be so slow... How can I do it through database?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it will make any difference. Even with hundreds of records, what you additionally have is one additional test on nil per record, and only one computation of 'Time.now'. Compared to the generation of the model objects, that is nearly nothing. You could compute the differences on storing, and then let the database compute the sum. But I would only do it if necessary (don't tune performance if it is not broken).

*EDIT*
If you have to compute the sum of the online times many times, you should compute the online time upfront when storing the offline timestamp:

1. Add by a migration the attribute `diff` as `integer` for the difference in minutes.
2. When storing your offline timestamp, compute as well the difference and store it together.
3. Add the sums by calling: `Model.sum("diff")`
4. Add to that the only record (there could be only one in your example) as @davidb has written in his solution.

Comment: Dude its not okay to to things in ruby when the database can do it faster and/or better. Of cause your right it doesnt matter when we talk about some hundred or even thousands of datasets but when you reach a higher level you might get some problems so its better to do it the right way from day one and not at the moment the application is as slow as a fusee.

Comment: I disagree here with you. To have a solution in Ruby which is fast enough is much easier to develop and maintain. And for the example, I don't see that you have millions of records (switching from offline to online), so no, don't optimize if it is not necessary. KISS!

Comment: Yes of cause thats easy but I dont think a solution in ruby including two pieces of SQL commands is that horrible to maintain. Its still ActiveRecord and no creepy pure SQL.

Comment: For example, if I have 700 records which I will use for calculations, difference is a 5 times. Difference between code lines is 2 vs 5. I think it is really convincing reason for usage DB for calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I think in that position it would be the easyes solution to do two queries. One exluding datasets where offline is NULL and one where only these are grabbed. Then you can use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP variable (It always contains the timestmap for actual time) of MySQL like this:

```
Model.where("offline IS NULL").sum("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-online")
```

then you can add the result of the first and secound query. Maybe made method function out of it:

```
def self.your_method_name_here
     secounds=0
     secounds+=Model.where("offline IS NOT NULL").sum("offline-online").to_i
     secounds+=Model.where("ofline IS NULL").sum("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-online").to_i
     secounds
end
```

It might be possible to do this in one query but I think this is quit practable!

Comment: Thanks! I'll immediately try this.

Comment: Seems everything is OK, but difference offline - online isn't currently in seconds :( Any suggessions?

Comment: Added some changes forget the .to_i

Comment: no :) I mean that DB returned incorrect result, for example 1500 for 15 minutes. I have that problem more than year ago, but I don't remember... I have done some conversions inside DB query for correct answer... I'll search. Have you problem like that?

Comment: 1500? It should return 900 secounds.

Comment: Found answer: Model.where("offline IS NOT NULL").sum("TIME_TO_SEC(offline-online)")
Is it normal for rails? :) Any improvements exists?